# Defining a Micronaut bean that starts before the Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: micronaut

I would like to use Flyway to migrate the database. In Grails (Spring) application one could simply define a custom bean and mark Hibernate SessionFactory depending on that bean.

```
flyway(Flyway) { bean ->
    bean.initMethod = 'migrate'
    dataSource = ref('dataSource')
    locations = 'classpath:migration/db/mysql'
    baselineOnMigrate = true
    table = 'schema_version'
}

if (springConfig.containsBean('hibernateDatastore')) {

    BeanDefinition beanToInlineWithFlyway = getBeanDefinition('hibernateDatastore')

    def dependsOnList = ['flyway'] as Set
    if (beanToInlineWithFlyway.dependsOn?.length > 0) {
        dependsOnList.addAll(beanToInlineWithFlyway.dependsOn)
    }
    beanToInlineWithFlyway.dependsOn = dependsOnList as String[]
}
```

Is there a way in Micronaut achieving the same?

**The reason why I like to do this is:**

When doing database migration with Flyway you delegate all the DDL stuff to Flyway and set Hibernate `jpa.default.properties.hibernate.hbm2dll.auto` to `validate`.

```
jpa:
  default:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: validate
```

Flyway will the start before Hibernate and will check if any migration of the database tables is necessary. After that Hibernate kicks in and validates the database schema against the current JPA entities.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: @JamesKleeh tried to explain why I would like to do this that way

Comment: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/817

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than relying on bean names which is brittle, you can instead define a bean that implements `BeanCreatedEventListener<DataSource>`. This would run after the `DataSource` bean is created but before the `SessionFactory` is created.